# How to pronounce 的 in 所有的?

Tags: pronunciation

In particular, in the song 耶稣喜爱世上小孩, the second line 世上所有的小孩 sounds as though it were pronounced shìshàng suóyǒu dì xiǎohái.  Is that correct?  Thank you for your help; my ear for Chinese is not yet well developed.

Comment: Your question has been discussed before, please see: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/318/why-is-%E7%9A%84-de-sometimes-pronounced-di-even-though-it-is-used-as-a-possessive-p

Comment: Ah, thank you @DrunkenMaster for pointing me to that question; I didn't find it before.  That discussion (along with the comments here) is very helpful.  Since it's beens so thoroughly answered before, maybe someone with a higher rep can close/flag my question as already answered?

Answer (score 6):

If it's on a downbeat, accented note, then definitely "di". If it's short and unaccented, then it really does not matter. It's probably why you could not tell when you heard it. If you are singing, sing "di" to play safe.

Answer (score 1):

的 is usually pronounced "de" (as in French), but in songs it is commonly pronounced "di".

Answer (score 0):

de silent tone(轻声)

di is more like a dialect.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> [d]

It is a very silent sound.